# Add Doubly Linked List Node in Singly Linked List

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

Given singly Linked List: `1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> null`
Modify middle element as doubly Linked List Node 
here middle element is `3`
`3 -> next` should point to `4`
`3 -> prev` should point to `1`

Can any one suggest how can it be done ? interviewer gave me hint `use interface`. but I couldn't figure it out how. 
I have to iterate over this linked list and print all the node and when it reaches to the middle, print where next and prev is pointing to, then print till the end of the list. 
`Expected output` : `1, 2, Middle: 3, Prev: 1, Next: 4, 5`

I'm facing problem in adding the middle node.

Comment: Shouldn't `prev(3)` = 2?

Comment: it can point to any node. but he asked me to point middle's prev node to first node.

Comment: Okay, and I'm not sure what the hint of "use interface" means because you'll need to modify the Node object of the list to have any different structure than a single link...

Comment: but how would you change the specific node object ?

Comment: Well, does every Node have a previous pointer? Otherwise, how would you even set `3 -> prev`? I would think not considering you are given a Singly Linked List.

Comment: if there were next & prev pointer for every node then it's DLL and very easy to manipulate, But that's not the problem statement.

Comment: Do you even ask the interviewer that? You're supposed to ask what the model classes look like and what methods/variables you have access to

Comment: Yes I did ask. He was very clear "SLL (data, next) and DLL (data, next, prev). Thanks cricket_007 for response.

Comment: From "use interface" it sounds like he wanted you to have the single and doubly linked list nodes implement a common `interface` type, so a previous or next node could point to either a singly or doubly linked list node.  I would run from this company asking such a silly question... run very fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this "*works*", but if this is expected to be answered on an interview, it is way too much work.

**LinkedList**

```
public class LinkedList {

    public interface Linkable<V, L extends Linkable> {
        V getValue();
        L getNext();
        void setNext(L link);
    }

    public static class Node implements Linkable<Integer, Linkable> {
        int value;
        Linkable next;

        Node(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        @Override
        public Integer getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        @Override
        public Linkable getNext() {
            return next;
        }

        @Override
        public void setNext(Linkable link) {
            this.next = link;
        }
    }

    private Linkable head;

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return this.head == null;
    }

    public Linkable getHead() {
        return head;
    }

    public void add(int v) {
        Node next = new Node(v);
        if (isEmpty()) {
            this.head = next;
        } else {
            Linkable tmp = this.head;
            while (tmp.getNext() != null) {
                tmp = tmp.getNext();
            }
            tmp.setNext(next);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Interface**

```
interface DoublyLinkable<V, L extends LinkedList.Linkable> extends LinkedList.Linkable<V,L> {
    LinkedList.Linkable getPrev();
    void setPrev(LinkedList.Linkable prev);
}
```

**DoubleNode**

```
public class DoubleNode extends LinkedList.Node implements DoublyLinkable<Integer, LinkedList.Linkable> {
    LinkedList.Linkable prev;

    public DoubleNode(int value) {
        super(value);
    }

    @Override
    public LinkedList.Linkable getPrev() {
        return prev;
    }

    @Override
    public void setPrev(LinkedList.Linkable prev) {
         this.prev = prev;
    }
}
```

---

**Driver**

Outputs

```
1, 2, Middle: 3, Prev: 1, Next: 4, 5
```

---

```
public class Driver {

    public static LinkedList getList() {
        LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            list.add(i);
        }
        return list;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LinkedList list = getList();

        LinkedList.Linkable head = list.getHead();
        LinkedList.Linkable beforeMiddle = null;
        LinkedList.Linkable middle = list.getHead();
        LinkedList.Linkable end = list.getHead();

        if (head != null) {
            // find the middle of the list
            while (true) {
                if (end.getNext() == null || end.getNext().getNext() == null) break;

                beforeMiddle = middle;
                middle = middle.getNext();

                end = end.getNext().getNext();
            }

            // Replace middle by reassigning the pointer to it
            if (beforeMiddle != null) {

                DoubleNode n = new DoubleNode((int) middle.getValue()); // same value
                n.setPrev(list.getHead()); // point back to the front
                n.setNext(middle.getNext()); // point forward to original value

                beforeMiddle.setNext((DoublyLinkable) n);
                middle = beforeMiddle.getNext();
            }

            // Build the "expected" output
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            final String DELIMITER = ", ";
            head = list.getHead();
            boolean atMiddle = false;
            if (head != null) {
                do {
                    if (head instanceof DoublyLinkable) {
                        atMiddle = true;
                        String out = String.format("Middle: %d, Prev: %d, ", (int) head.getValue(), (int) ((DoublyLinkable) head).getPrev().getValue());
                        sb.append(out);
                    } else {
                        if (atMiddle) {
                            sb.append("Next: ");
                            atMiddle = false;
                        }
                        sb.append(head.getValue()).append(DELIMITER);
                    }

                    head = head.getNext();
                } while (head != null);
            }
            sb.setLength(sb.length() - DELIMITER.length());

            System.out.println(sb.toString());
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By *definition*, a single-linked list consists of single-linked nodes only,  and a double-linked consists of double-linked nodes only. Otherwise. it is neither.

By *definition* the field `prev` of a double-linked list *must* point to the previous element.

Whatever you are supposed to build. It's something not well specified. So if you really were asked this in an interview (and did not misunderstand the question - maybe he wanted you to point out that ghis *violates* the interface?) this is a case for the code horror stories of http://thedailywtf.com/ - section "incompetent interviewers".

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't, you'd better define a lenght() function so given one linked list you can know how many nodes does it have.

Thanks to the response of Cereal_Killer to the previous version of this answer, I noticed that the list is firstly a singly linked list, and you just have to make the middle node be linked both to the next node and to some previous node.

Now I guess that you have defined two structures (Struct, Class or whatever depending on the language you're using). So lets say you have `Node_s` defined as a node with only a `next` pointer, and `Node_d` with both a `next` and a `prev` pointer. (`Node_d` may inherite from `Node_s` so you just have to add the `prev` attribute in the child class). Knowing this, the code above should be doing what you need:

function do_it(my_LinkedList linkedList){

```
    int i_middle;
    int length = linkedList.length();

    if ( (length ÷ 2 ) != 0 ) i_middle = length / 2;
    else return -1; 

    Node_s aux = linkedList.first();
    int index = 0;
    Node_d middle= null;

    while (aux != null) {

       if (index == i_middle - 1){ //now aux is the middle's previous node

            middle.data = aux.next.data; //aux.next is the middle singly node, we assignate the data to the new double linked node

            middle.prev = aux; //as we said, aux is the prev to the middle
            midle.next = aux.next.next; //so aux.next.next is the next to the middle
            print(what you need to print);
       }else {
            print("Node " + index " next:  "+ aux.next);
       }//end if

       index++;
       aux = aux.next;
    } //end while

}//end function
```

This previous code should be doing what you need. I wrote the answer in some kind of pseudo-java code so if you're not familiar with Java or don't understand what my pseudo-code does, please let me know. Anyway, the idea of my code may present some troubles depending on the language you're working with, so you'll have to adapt it.

Note that at the end of the execution of this program, your data structure won't be a singly linked list, and neither a double one, since you'll have `linkedList.length() - 1` nodes linked in a signly way but the middle one will have two links.

Hope this helps.

Comment: if you have a singly linked list then finding number of node is not a problem. It's clearly mentioned in the problem statement "Insert Doubly Linked List Node to Singly Linked List". Singly Linked List will have "data and next" where Doubly Linked List will have "data, next, prev"

Comment: Thanks Miquel for the response. But It's not a Doubly Linked List. :)

Comment: Okay, I worked on a new answer, let me know if it's what you're looking for or I missed something about your specifications!

Comment: problem is with the implementation. Please provide the solution in any of the programming language. I understood the logic. Thanks !

Comment: Nice! Please read my answer again since I made some changes and I don't know if you read it before or after changing it. Other than that, what do you need more? The whole project implementation? I mean, the whole list implementation and everything or just the code in my answer?